# Java: Exit Confirmation on game

Tags: java

The code works fine until it reaches the no option, once clicked the no option stutters and then closes. on the other hand, the yes option works fine and closes instantly. "loader.cleanUP();" is for removing the vbos and vaos, therefore, it is needed. would appreciate some help.

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        renderer.render(model);         
        renderer.prepare();
        // add logic!
        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
    }
        int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to exit?", "Exit Confirmation", dialogButton);

        if(dialogResult == 0) {
          System.out.println("Yes option");
          loader.cleanUP();
          System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a while loop at the very start, checking for close requests and rendering the model. Once a close is requested, you break out of this loop, *regardless of whether the user clicked yes or no*. You need to wrap all of the code shown in another loop, which simply runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your `while` to a `do-while`.
2. Don't exit with `System.exit(0);`...The API you're using probably has an exit method of it's own, that unloads the resources before exiting. This is necessary because, usually, resources will be loaded to GPU and will not be unloaded by Java's native methods (only by the API's specialized methods).
3. If your API has such, use `Display.setCloseRequested(true)` (or similar), instead of this `int dialogResult` gimmick. This is related to how you will exit the game while avoiding `System.exit(0);`, as instructed in the previous item.
4. If your API doesn't provide it's own, you need a separate loop to run the game-world within. Preferably implementing `Delta-Time` to maintain the animations without *time-drift* bugs.